# Clear list of distinctions between an API, Library, Framework, and Toolkit in Java

Tags: java, terminology

I've lots of varying definitions for the following terms, but I'm not clear as to the distinctions between them. Would someone please clarify the following and the distinction(s) between each item?

- API
- Library
- Framework
- Toolkit

I'm not seeing what makes an API different from a library or a toolkit from a framework or a framework from a library.

Comment: Already covered on PSE: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/54451/library-vs-framework-vs-api

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These terms' uses vary considerably and there's lots of overlap between them, but here's the uses that I most commonly encounter:

- An API is a specification of how to communicate with a piece of software from a program.
- A library is a collection of classes that you can import and use in your program. A library comes with an API.
- A framework is like a library, but turned inside out: instead of using it as a component in your program, you write your program to conform to some interface and plug it into the framework. A framework is something you build *in*, while a library is something you build *on*.
- A toolkit is a set of programs that work *on* programs, such as compilers, debuggers, editors, etc. (But some libraries are also called toolkits.)

Of course, a framework will commonly come with a library of common operations, or be structured as a set of libraries and may include tools. Toolkit is the most loosely defined of these terms, I think.

Comment: That is where the confusion was, with the overlap. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the developer they are not really all that different.  The API, or Application Programming Interface is what developers are interested in, because it's the way developers use the tools.

When trying to distinguish between Library, Framework, and Toolkit, you are really just talking about semantics.

I suppose if you got into it, a Library would be a subset of a Framework, since a Framework might contain some Libraries.

Answer (score 1):

There's some difference but it's not a clear-cut (well defined) distinction. In many contexts that differences are next to nothing. That said, here's the rough distinction:

- Library: a collection of reusable s/w units (functions, classes, etc.).
- API: The protocol that some unit in your program exposes. This unit can be of any size (including a composite unit containing smaller units) . In particular, it can be a library.
- Framework: a library that imposes some strict restriction on the code using it. Typically, it takes over the control flow and calls your code when/if it decides (through some callback mechanism). In some sense, it's not that "your code use the framework" but rather "the framework uses your code".
- Toolkit: a library that is not a framework.